# solving trigonometric equation $3^{\sin^2(x)}+3^{\cos^2(x)}=4$

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me to solve this trigonometric equation.

> $$3^{\sin^2(x)}+3^{\cos^2(x)}=4.$$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

Let $3^{\cos^2x}=a$

$\displaystyle 3^{\sin^2x}=3^{1-\cos^2x}=\frac3{3^{\cos^2x}}=\frac3a$

So,we have $\displaystyle \frac3a+a=4\iff a^2-4a+3=0\iff a=1,3$

If $a=1,$ $3^{\cos^2x}=1=3^0\iff \cos^2x=0\iff \cos x=0,x=(2n+1)\frac\pi2$

If $a=3,$ $3^{\cos^2x}=3=3^1\iff \cos^2x=1\iff \sin x=0,x=n\pi=2n\frac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

So, the answer reduces to any [integral] multiple of $\frac\pi2,$ right?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Let $t=3^{\sin^2 x}$ then the equation is equivalent to (using $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$)
$$t+\frac{3}{t}=4\iff t^2-4t+3=0, \ t\ne0$$
and the roots are $t_1=1$ and $t_2=3$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome:)

Answer (score 2):

$$3^{\sin^2x}+3^{\cos^2x}=4\implies 3^{1-\cos^2x}+3^{\cos^2x}=4\implies$$

Putting $\;a:=\cos^2x$ :

$$\frac3{3^a}+3^a=4\implies 3^{2a}-4\cdot3^a+3=0\iff (3^a-3)(3^a-1)=0\implies$$

$$\implies \begin{cases}3^a=3\implies \color{red}{a=1}&\;or\\{}\\3^a=1\implies \color{red}{a=0}\end{cases}$$

and from here

$$\begin{cases}\cos^2x=1\iff \color{green}{x=n\pi}\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z&,\;\;or\\{}\\\cos^2x=0\iff \color{green}{x=\frac{2n-1}2\pi}\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $3^{\cos^2x}=a,$ $3^{\sin^2x}=b$.  Then $a b=3.$ We got the simple system of equations
$$
\left \{  \begin{array}{l} a+b=4,\\ a b=3  \end{array} \right.
$$
By solving it we get $a=1,3, b=3,1$. Then you may continue as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $$3^{\sin^2x}+3^{\cos^2x}=4=3+1=3^1+3^0$$

$$\therefore 3^{\sin^2x}+3^{\cos^2x}=3^1+3^0$$

Comparing LHS and RHS,
$$\sin^2 x=1$$
$$\cos^2 x =0$$

Or $$\sin^2 x=0$$
$$\cos^2 x=1$$

$\because \sin 0=\cos 90=0$ and $\cos 0=\sin 90=1$,

We get $x=0$ or $x=90$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You must prove that these are the only solutions, and this is the difficult part.